# Error while trying to get download URL from firebase-storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I've been trying to get download URL for the an image in my firebase-storage but it keeps throwing an object-does-not-exist error. Any clue what the problem might be? I'm certain the directories match up and there is a profilePhoto.jpg file in the firebase-storage directory.

```
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref() //root reference;
var usersRef = storageRef.child('users/');
var userPaths = []; //list of all users

usersRef.listAll()
    .then(res => {
        for (var i = 0; i < res.prefixes.length; i++) {
            userPaths[i] = res.prefixes[i].location.path_;
        }
        
        var photoRef = storageRef.child(`${userPaths[0]}/profilePhoto.jpg`);
        photoRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {...});
    });
```

This is the error:

> FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Object 'users/6TitxcYcENhRHXDy0Xatk4ODQKo2/profilePhoto.jpg' does not exist.

Comment: The error is not likely to be incorrect, but we can't verify this for you since we can't see the contents of your storage bucket to make sure the path you requested actually exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm with Doug here: I have never seen Firebase give that error message if the file actually exists, so it's more likely that something is wrong in the mapping.

If you can't spot it, maybe you can show a screenshot of the file in the Firebase console, or see if the file shows up when you [request a list of files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files).

Comment: Thanks! I should have tested that but I'm pretty new to js & firebase if you couldn't tell. I listed the files and used the final path and it worked. The only difference between the paths was that the listed path (the one that worked) didn't have a .jpg ending? So the problem was with my path not the code or the mapping.

Comment: `profilePhoto` and `profilePhoto.jpg` are different files, so it makes sense that the lookup failed. Good to hear you found it.